# Serial Number does not show by Grouping Row Number in RDLC Report

Tags: .net, rdlc, reportbuilder3.0

I am working with RDLC Report Builder 3.0. In my report page i have created two group and it's working fine. But I want to set serial number according to parent group.

**I have written an expression though, but it's does not work:**

```
=Runningvalue(Fields!VehicleId.Value,CountDistinct,"VehicleId")
```

**For this output:**
[image]

**I need:** 
[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `VehicleId` isn't your dataset. So, You've to write your expression like :

```
=Runningvalue(Fields!VehicleId.Value,CountDistinct,"YourDataSetName")
```

Hopefully, this might solve your problem.